# LocomotiveCMS has_many/belongs_to not working

Tags: locomotivecms

For some reason I cannot get the has_many/belongs_to relationship to work. The nested content type does not show up in the parent. Here is what I have:

app/content_types/news_photos.yml

```
- article:
    label: News articles
    type: belongs_to
    target: news_articles
```

app/content_types/news_articles.yml

```
- news_photos:
    label: News photos
    type: has_many
    target: news_photos
    class_name: news_photos
    inverse_of: news_article
    required: false
    hint: A description of the field for the editors
    localized: false
    ui_enabled: true
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: it seems like a mistake in the naming convention. Try some generator examples from tutorials and compare.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you got to the solution but the issue is in fact in naming.
The `has_many` definition should have `inverse_of: article`

The value of `inverse_of` should be the name of the attribute that has the `belongs_to` relation in other model, in this case `news_photos`.